# Is equality $\neg \neg$-stable?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In an essay by Andrej Bauer, I read the following statement : "A statement built from the universal quantifier ∀, conjunction ∧, implication ⇒, and numerical equality = is ¬¬-stable, as can be easily verified"

I could of course verify that the set of $\neg\neg$-stable sentences (i.e. sentences $\varphi$ such that $\vdash \neg\neg\varphi \to \varphi$ is intuitionistically derivable) is stable under these constructions ($\forall, \land, \implies$), it's relatively easy; but I could not prove that for terms $s,t$, $\vdash \neg\neg(s=t) \to s=t$ was actually derivable, and it actually seemed wrong, because of what follows.

Indeed it would be surprising if it were true because right after it, when talking about synthetic differential geometry, he notes that an infinitesimal $d$ ($d^2= 0$) is not unequal to $0$, i.e. $\neg\neg(d=0)$ holds, but obviously if $d=0$ held it would be uninteresting for synthetic differential geometry. So I'm guessing there's something I misunderstood about the first statement. If so, what does it mean more precisely, what's wrong with my understanding ?

ADDED: [Here's](http://math.andrej.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/real-world-realizability.pdf) a link to the paper in question, the quote is from a note on page 3.

As suggested in the comments, the problem is probably related to the adjective "numerical" in the quote, but I can't really make sense of it. Note that this isn't about Heyting arithmetic (where $m=n \lor m\neq n$ is provable by induction) since the statement here is applied to the laws of physics, laws that usually require at least the real numbers

Comment: It might related to the modifier "numerical" in "numerical equality."

Comment: Is this about Heyting arithmetic? If so then you can prove by induction that the law of excluded middle holds for atomic predicates.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : sure but what would it mean then ?

Comment: @RobArthan : since this is about physics I'd say it's about real numbers

Comment: That was purely guesswork on my part, I'm out of my league on this topic.

Comment: I think you need to cite the paper.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. I too am baffled by what Bauer says.

Comment: "A statement built from the universal quantifier ∀, conjunction ∧, implication ⇒, and numerical equality = is ¬¬-stable" ... so like, no object variables?  No propositional variables?  No numerical constants?  No numerical functions?  An arbitrary propositional variable cannot be "¬¬-stable" stable because that is equivalent to assuming LEM.  If you say "numerical equality", then what are your numerical axioms?

Comment: @DanielV : well that's what I'm trying to understand, this quote isn't mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrej was referring to equality on real numbers, since he was referring to physical laws, which are usually formulated using real numbers. It's true that equality cannot be shown to be stable in general, but it is stable for real numbers.

Here is a bit more background.

- Equality on natural numbers is stable, even decidable, that is for any given natural numbers $n$ and $m$, we have $n = m$ or $\neg(n = m)$. This can be proven by induction.
- Equality on rational numbers is decidable.
- Equality on real numbers can fail to be decidable, constructively. (The intuition for this failure is: Given a number $x$ in the form of a machine which can output more and more digits of $x$, it's not possible to determine in finite time whether $x = 0$ or $\neg(x = 0)$, because $x$ might start like $0.00000000$. This intuition can be made precise using realizability theory or the effective topos. If we would allow machines to run for longer than infinity, the situation is different. See [these slides](https://rawgit.com/iblech/mathezirkel-kurs/master/superturingmaschinen/slides-warwick2017.pdf) for more.)

  However equality on real numbers is still stable. This has a deeper reason: The fundamental relation on real numbers is not actually equality, but *apartness*, written $\#$. Numbers are apart from each other if and only if they have a positive distance (which is if and only if a rational number fits strictly inbetween the given numbers). It then turns out that $x = y$ iff $\neg(x \# y)$. (We say that the apartness is *tight*.) Hence $\neg\neg(x = y)$ is $\neg\neg\neg(x \# y)$, and three negations can always be simplified to one.
- Equality on complex numbers is stable but might fail to be decidable, for the same reasons.
- Equality on algebraic numbers is (stable and) decidable! The extra information contained in a witness of algebraicity (a monic polynomial with rational coefficients) suffices to make the case distinction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but then how does it work for synthetic differential geometry ? Because if $d^2=0$, then $\neg\neg (d=0)$ (or at least I remember reading that somewhere) and so if equality is stable this means $d=0$ : there is no synthetic differential geometry ! But of course there  is, so where am I going wrong ?

Comment: @Max: Excellent observation. I should have been moe precise. In my answer I was referring to the Cauchy reals or the Dedekind reals. The reals in synthetic differential geometry are yet a different flavor. (I don't know of any intrinsic characterization, they just happen to be the image of the manifold $\mathbb{R}^1$ under the embedding $\mathrm{Mnf} \to \mathcal{E}$ in a chosen well-adapted model of SDG.) The reals in SDG satisfy $\neg(x = 0) \Rightarrow x \text{ invertible}$, but not $\neg(x \text{ invertible}) \Rightarrow x = 0$. You would need the latter to verify that equality is stable.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, so I was mistaking the different kinds of reals ! Would it be interesting to have an intronsic characterization of those reals ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I wouldn't really know where to start. A related quest is to give an intrinsic characterization of the subsheaf of those continuous real-valued functions (recall that this sheaf just looks like the set of Dedekind reals from the internal point of view) which happen to be differentiable or smooth. This problem is a bit better delimited. (But open for several decades. Probably no such characterization exists. Depends on the precise definitions.) See [here](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/6315/internal-definitions-of-cohesion/), esp. comment 19 by Mike, for details.